# merge multiple citations (using rsc.bst & bookends)

Tags: bibtex

I am using rsc.bst as the bibiliography style of my text. It can merge multiple citations in one refer ence entry by adding an asterisk to every of the citation keys following the lead one, for example:

`\cite{ref1,*ref2,*ref3}`

result:
1ref1;(b)ref2;(c)ref3.

sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}
\begin{document}
 polar bears are not polar \cite{ref1,*ref2,*ref3}
\bibliography{text}
\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\end{document}
```

However, it seems that Bookends can't recognize the asterisk as something special thus not able to match the citations mark with stars. My current solution is to scan the text and compile the bib file without the asterisks, and add them afterwards. It is getting inconvenient when I need to add more citations and have to rescan the text with Bookends. Did you probably encounter same problem and have better solutions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not loading `mciteplus`, so the starred-reference 'magic' will not be available. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by 'bookends'.

Comment: @JosephWright Nah, this is more of an [editor](http://www.sonnysoftware.com/bookends/bookends.html) question.

Comment: Oh thanks for the heads-up @JosephWright. I did use mciteplus in my original manuscript but just forgot to add in the posted question.

Comment: I have actually posted the same question in the official Bookends forum before coming here, but now it seems none from both sides has encountered the same problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really a feature request for Bookends (which currently doesn't recognise the `*` notation of `mciteplus`).